# Best Way to Upgrade from WP 2.8 (!)?

Tags: upgrade, virus

I offered a friend to help translate from English some parts of his (mostly) Hebrew install. Then he told me two things:

1) That he's running 2.8 (he was worried about updating because he didn't want the design to break)

and 2) That he has reason to suspect that the site is infected with a trojan horse since it gets blocked by some antiviruses.

1) What is the best way to go about upgrading? is it even feasible to start on a fresh installation and still have everything intact? including redirects? or will I have to go about it as per WP's documentation: step by step upgrading.

2) What can be done about the trojan horse? this is why I'm contemplating a fresh install, which I know is probably not recommended.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The virus part is going to be off-topic, but yes a fresh install is the way to go.

What I would do to upgrade the site is:

1. Backup everything-- PHP and database
2. Install the old site on a development server.
3. Before running the site, replace all of the core files with new 2.8
   ones [from the archive](http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/). This will hopefully fix the suspected virus problem.
4. Then start [updating release by release](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended) until you get current. Do not
   try to leap-frog over more than one or two ***minor*** releases.
5. Then you can fix anything that is broken. Unless the original site
   is running hacked core files I don't think this step will be too
   much trouble, though you will have `Notice`s to fix and perhaps a
   few other things.

The reason I recommend upgrading release by release, rather than trying to upgrade all at once, are:

1. Personal experience
2. I've seen a lot of issues over on the wordpress.org forums
   apparently caused by jumping too many releases
3. There is note in the Codex to this effect ["... it's okay to skip one
   release, but never skip TWO when upgrading."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended)

I have looked at the
    upgrade code and, yes, it seems like WordPress should upgrade itself
    over multiple releases but does not always appear to do so
    correctly-- perhaps issues like timeouts get in the way.

Comment: Thanks; Unfortunately the virus is affected theme files as well and inserted JS files. 

(Aside: I'm at risk if I'm running a Mac? should I just leave this problem be and avoid helping? I don't want that)

Also, the site is 3.0 GB in size, do I need to move the images too?

Comment: Would you suggest doing the changes ON SITE after the back up?

Comment: I would never recommend doing any work on a live site, short of absolute emergencies. Work on a copy on a dev server. I don't know enough about what has infected the site to answer your questions about security. However, if the theme is infected, worries about breaking it are minor. You need to go thorough it line by line anyway.

Comment: It shows for some users as JS/Agent. NKW Trojan. I'm just not sure if it's the right thing to do now - download 3GB and then upload them (at ~100kb/sec for the upload). Is there any way to avoid downloading the images?

Comment: Is there a way to do a COMPLETLEY fresh install and just migrate the images + database + (clean) theme..that is, without losing things like links and keeping each post with its current id as before?

Comment: The problem with a completely fresh install is that the database would not be incrementally updated as it would be if you update through each release, though you could at #2 install brand new 2.8.

Comment: I am curious what are you basing recommendation to upgrade release by release on? I don't think I've seen that recommended in Codex (small authority it is, but still) and as far as I know WP is engineered to update over several versions just fine.

Comment: @Rarst : 1) Personal experience, 2) I've seen a lot of issues over on the wordpress.org forums apparently caused by jumping too many releases, 3) there is note in the Codex to this effect "... it's okay to skip one release, but never skip TWO when upgrading." I have looked at the upgrade code and, yes, it seems like WordPress _should_ upgrade itself over multiple releases but does not always appear to do so correctly-- perhaps issues like timeouts get in the way.